# Code to calculate angle not working

Tags: java, math

I am trying to calculate the angle in degrees between tow points in java.  This is the code i am using to calculate the angle.

```
public static double calcAngle(Point.Double p1, Point.Double p2)
{
    double xDiff = p2.x - p1.x;
    double yDiff = p2.y - p1.y;
    return Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(yDiff, xDiff));
}
```

Here is the rest of my code

```
double playerX = panel.getCharacter().getX();
double playerY = panel.getCharacter().getY();
int dispenserX = x*Block.WIDTH;
int dispenserY = y*Block.HEIGHT;
Point2D.Double player = new Point2D.Double(playerX, playerY);
Point2D.Double dispenser = new Point2D.Double(dispenserX, dispenserY);
double angle = calcAngle(dispenser, player);
System.out.println(angle);
panel.addEntity(newEntityFireball(x*Block.WIDTH,y*Block.HEIGHT,angle,1));//adds a fireball at a 45 degree angle
System.out.println(angle);
System.out.println(dispenser);
System.out.println(player);
```

The fireball fired from the dispenser is not aimed at the player why? And it seems to move at a random angle.

Edit here is the fireball class

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class EntityFireball extends Entity 
{
    private double angle;
    private double speed;
    private int life;

    public EntityFireball(double x, double y, double angle, double speed) 
    {
        super(x, y, 20, 20);
        this.angle = angle;
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public void update(boolean inRange)
    {
        life++;

        if(life>2500)
            removeEntityFromGame(this);

        if(inRange)
        {
            float xDirection = (float) (Math.sin((float) Math.toRadians(angle)) * speed);
            float yDirection = (float) (Math.cos((float) Math.toRadians(angle)) * -speed);
            double newX = getX() + xDirection;
            double newY = getY() + yDirection;
            setX(newX);
            setY(newY);
        }
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage() 
    {
        try
        {
            return ImageIO.read(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/images/Fireball.png"));
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: What were you expecting? Using the +x axis as the base for the angle that's in the -x direction and slightly down, which seems about right to me?

Comment: Looks about right to me. What result are you expecting?

Comment: why would it return a - degree when the seocnd point is higer than the first point

Comment: What's the "degree between two points"? Two points are always on the same line. Is the third point implied as the origin `(0,0)`?

Comment: what i am saying is if you have a horizontal line on point1 i want to know how far it has to be rotated to reach point2 in degrees.  Or phrased differently i want to know the rotation of a line between point 1 and point 2

Comment: If your points are in screen coords, then yDiff = p1.y - p2.y as Screen Y(0) is at top

Comment: Apparently not, since you didn't bother to indicate what "that" is.

Comment: I was asking weather it was significant if it was in screen coords

Comment: Radians vs degrees problem probably

Comment: i dont think so i call Math.toDegrees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
float xDirection = (float) (Math.sin((float) Math.toRadians(angle)) * speed);
float yDirection = (float) (Math.cos((float) Math.toRadians(angle)) * -speed);
```

to

```
float xDirection = (float) (Math.cos((float) Math.toRadians(angle)) * speed);
float yDirection = (float) (Math.sin((float) Math.toRadians(angle)) * speed);
```

Also, you are changing the 2D course vector into an angle, and then changing it back to a 2D course vector.  It's a decent amount of circular trig that lands you the same answer that you initially started with.  Is there a reason you don't just leave it a vector?

```
public static Point2D.Double calcAngle(Point.Double p1, Point.Double p2){
    double xDiff = p2.x - p1.x;
    double yDiff = p2.y - p1.y;
    return new Point2D.Double(xDiff,yDiff);
}


public class EntityFireball extends Entity {
    private Point2D.Double course;
    private double speed;
    private int life;

    public EntityFireball(double x, double y, double angle, Point2D.Double course){
        super(x, y, 20, 20);
        this.angle = angle;
        this.course=course;
    }

    public void update(boolean inRange){
        life++;
        if(life>2500)
            removeEntityFromGame(this);

        if(inRange){
            float xDirection = course.x;
            float yDirection = course.y;
            double newX = getX() + xDirection;
            double newY = getY() + yDirection;
            setX(newX);
            setY(newY);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to keep it as degrees because i use fixed angles in other parts of my game

Answer (score 1):

Just take the absolute values:

```
public static double calcAngle(Point.Double p1, Point.Double p2)
{
    double xDiff = Math.abs(p2.x - p1.x);
    double yDiff = Math.abs(p2.y - p1.y);
    return Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(yDiff, xDiff));
}
```

Comment: @JoshSobel What exactly isn't working? This works fine for me.

Comment: The fireball is missing the player look at my updated question

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you've converted the angle to degrees but are treating it later as a radian angle when you do your drawing.  That would explain why it's in "random directions"

Comment: but when i use it in radians i then call toRadians look at my updated post